# ExpandableListView not expanding

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I used below code to set `onGroupClickListener` in `MainActivity` and I also set the `OnLongClickListener` to view within `getGroupView()` of my Custom adapter named `MyExpandableListAdapter`.

And then when I run the program `onGroupClickListener` never fire either I return true or false from the `OnGroupClickListener()` .If i remove `OnlongClickListener` from `getGroupView()` program  run normally and `onGroupClickListener()` will fire! What's happening here and how to solve?

If no that mean there is no way to set `longClickListener` to groups of a `ExpandableListView`?!!!Here is the code for `OnGroupClickListener()` in MainActivity

```
exListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {                               
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(),(Bitmap[]) exListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, 7)));             
            lastClickedGroup=groupPosition;                 
            return false;               
        }

    });
```

and here is the code for long press in MyExpandableListAdapter:

```
arg2.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            DetailDialog.getDialog(screen.getContext(),(String)getChild(arg0,5));
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you

```
exListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {                               
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(),(Bitmap[]) exListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, 7)));             
            lastClickedGroup=groupPosition;                 
            exListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);//UPDATE HERE
            return false;               
        }

    });
```

Comment: Sorry biraj onGroupClick() not called when onLongClick() setted.

Comment: return false from setOnLongClickListener() method